# The meaning of "crowned face" in "Drywall Hammer with Shock Reduction Grip and Scored and Crowned Face"

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does "crowned face" in the following sentence mean "[a face of a polyhedron produced by the removal of a summit not in the base](https://www.wordnik.com/words/crown-face#:%7E:text=from%20The%20Century%20Dictionary.,summit%20not%20in%20the%20base.)"? Thank you!

"[Estwing 14 Oz Drywall Hammer with Shock Reduction Grip and Scored and Crowned Face](https://www.homedepot.ca/product/estwing-14-oz-drywall-hammer-with-shock-reduction-grip-and-scored-and-crowned-face/1000102935?mi_u=65847003&mi_ecmp=em_20221031_en_pro_wmh_wk39_best-value_dyn_engaged-0-6-ab&mi_country_code=CA&mi_postal_code=T3H0P3&eid=EM_20221031_EN_PRO_WMH_WK39_BEST-VALUE_DYN_ENGAGED-0-6-AB*_SEC_O_SKU_D23&em=&ET_MID=63181474&ET_RID=65847003&mi_cmp=033bd2344381e5e4&mi_sc=t)"

Comment: I get "access denied" for the "Estwing ..." link.

Comment: @AdrianHHH - me too, but you can Google Image search for the text.

Comment: The definition you found sounds like a definition from geometry, a branch of mathematics.

Comment: crown (verb, trans) To cause to round upward; to make anything higher at the middle than at the edges, such as the face of a machine pulley.  (wiktionary)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a specialist tool-related term. The term 'crown (or crowned) face' used about a hammer means that the hammer is a special type that has a flat or slightly convex ('crowned') striking surface. They are used for specialist work like panel beating.

The hammer in this picture has one square and one round 'crowned face'

[image]

This is probably the hammer you are writing about. You can see the crown (crowned) face has a pattern of 'scores' (grooves):

[image]

The shock reduction grip is the blue soft covering around the handle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The face of a hammer is the part that strikes the item being hammered. A crowned face to a hammer means the edges of the face are rounded so as to prevent (or at least reduce) marks from the edges. Web searches for "parts of a hammer" and for "crowned face hammer" provide relevant information.

I do not understand the "polyhedron" link but it appears not relevant.

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your detailed explanations!